# can i convert steam games in my library to my steam gift inventory?

Tags: steam

is it possible to move steam games in your library to your steam gift inventory? i would like to trade my games for keys/metal/unusual's for tf2 but i can't figure out how to do so. Is it even possible? please help :P

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Once a game has been downloaded it is un-tradable. If you want to gift a game then it must be purchased as a gift, or be gifted and obtained through a trade.